# How to use a custom PyTorch HoVer-Net model in the TIAToolBox for Nucleus Segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, machine-learning-model

I want to use the [TIAToolBox](https://github.com/TissueImageAnalytics/tiatoolbox) to [segment nuclei in tissue images](https://github.com/TissueImageAnalytics/tiatoolbox/blob/develop/examples/08-nucleus-instance-segmentation.ipynb). The pretrained models don't fit my demands. Therfore [I trained a custom HoVer-Net model](https://pathml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/link_train_hovernet.html) on the [PanNuke dataset](https://jgamper.github.io/PanNukeDataset/) to detect/count nuclei in tissue images.

The output I got is a .pt file.

Now I am looking for a way to use my custom PyTorch HoVer-Net model in the TIAToolBox.
I tried putting it in the same folder the pretrained models are in, but that didn't work.
I also tried loading the model using torch, and injecting it into the NucleusInstanceSegmentor, but that didn't work either:

Current approach:

```
n_classes_pannuke = 6

# load the model
hovernet = HoVerNet(n_classes=n_classes_pannuke)

# wrap model to use multi-GPU
hovernet = torch.nn.DataParallel(hovernet)

hovernet.load_state_dict(torch.load("hovernet_best_perf.pt"))
hovernet.eval();

# Tile prediction
inst_segmentor = NucleusInstanceSegmentor(
    model=hovernet,
    num_loader_workers=2,
    num_postproc_workers=2,
    batch_size=4,
)

# Analyse the images
tile_output = inst_segmentor.predict(
    imgs_to_predict,
    save_dir="sample_tile_results/",
    mode="tile",
    on_gpu=ON_GPU,
    crash_on_exception=True,
)
```

Error:
`ValueError: Must provide either ioconfig or patch_input_shape and patch_output_shape`

Does anybody know, how to use a custom PyTorch HoVer-Net model in the TIAToolBox to detect nuclei?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an `ioconfig` object first and use it with the `predict` function, for example:

```
iostate = IOSegmentorConfig(
input_resolutions=[
    {"units": "mpp", "resolution": 1.0},
],
output_resolutions=[
    {"units": "mpp", "resolution": 1.0},
],
patch_input_shape=[512, 512],
patch_output_shape=[512, 512],
stride_shape=[512, 512],
save_resolution={"units": "mpp", "resolution": 1.0},)
```

You can refer to the toolbox's example on how to use custom models [here](https://github.com/TissueImageAnalytics/tiatoolbox/blob/develop/examples/07-advanced-modeling.ipynb).